# About Fraction class in py3

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point, fractions

Is there is a way to find the number at `kth` position after the decimal point in `float` representation of a fraction? `k` is up to `10^6`.
I tried converting `float(Fraction)` to `str`, it didn't give me desired precision.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39612084/270986 for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module in Python (comes out of the box with Python).

```py
from decimal import *

division = 5 / 3
print(division)  # 1.6666666666666667

getcontext().prec = 6
division = Decimal(5) / Decimal(3)
print(division)  # 1.66667
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use a high-precision floating-point package like `decimal` to compute this, but if all you need is a single digit then there are more efficient methods: we can compute the trillionth digit (for example) of `34/23` (for example) in a fraction of a second using integers no larger than `1000` for the entire calculation.

Here's a simple function that gives the `k`th digit after the point of the fraction `p/q`:

```
def digit(p, q, k):
    """
    Return the kth digit after the point (k >= 1)
    of the fraction p / q.  p, q and k should be integers.
    """
    return pow(10, k-1, q) * p % q * 10 // q
```

And an example: 34/23 has decimal expansion `1.4782608695652173913043478260869565217...`, so let's use the above function to get some digits from that expansion

```
>>> digit(34, 23, 1)
4
>>> digit(34, 23, 3)
8
>>> digit(34, 23, 20)
0
>>> digit(34, 23, 30)
6
>>> digit(34, 23, 1_000_000_000)  # billionth digit after the point
5
```

Here's an explanation for why this works, using `34/23` as an example: suppose we wanted to compute the 5th place after the decimal point. Here's how we might do this by hand: we first multiply by `10**4` to move the places before the required digit to the left of the point:

> 10**4 * 34 / 23 = 14782.608695652173913043478260869565217...

Now we throw away the integer part and keep just the fractional part:

> fractional part = 0.608695652173913043478260869565217...

Then we multiply by 10 to get the desired digit just to the left of the decimal point:

> 10 * fractional part = 6.08695652173913043478260869565217...

And finally we throw away the fractional part of the result, keeping just the `6`, which is the digit we want.

All these operations are easy to do efficiently computationally: the fractional part of `10**(k-1) * p / q` is `(10**(k-1) * p % q) / q`, and we can compute `10**(k-1)*p % q` efficiently in Python using the three argument form of `pow` as `pow(10, k-1, q) * p % q`. Now write `r` for the numerator, and we want to compute the integer part of `r * 10 / q`. But that's just `r * 10 // q`, using Python's integer division operator.

So the whole thing becomes just:

```
pow(10, k-1, q) * p % q * 10 // q
```